# How can I use Underscore.js to transform/obfuscate each value in an object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use Underscore.js to step through an object and transform/obfuscate each value, so that:

```
{
  "weather": "Cloudy",
  "degrees": 90
}
```

becomes:

```
{
  "weather": "Claido",
  "degrees": 21
}
```

The completely incomprehensible reason- I'm trying to obfuscate JSON objects without ruining their structure. So if it's string, I replace any vowel with another random vowel. If it's a digit, I just pick another random digit, booleans are set randomly, and so on. I can build each element type manipulation, I'm just now sure how to recursively do it.

I can do something like this:

```
var t = { "weather":"Cloudy", "degrees": 12, "snowing": false };
var newObj = {};
var g = _.each(t, function(value, key, list) {
  if (_.isString(value)){
     newObj[key] = value.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
  }
  if (_.isNumber(value)){
     var n = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
     newObj[key] = n + value;
  }
  if (_.isBoolean(value)){
    newObj[key] = Math.random() >= 0.5;
  }
});
console.log(newObj);
```

And all is well. The problem is with arrays and nested objects like so:

```
{
 "weather": "Cloudy",
 "outsideWeather": {
     "forecast": "Stormy",
     "outside": 48
 },
 "degrees": 12,
 "snowing": false
}
```

My simple Switch cases break down at that point. Any ideas how to recursively step through each value, transform it, then build the object back to it's original structure?

Many thanks

Comment: *"The completely incomprehensible reason"* - word. On topic: just use some simple recursion.

Comment: I'm very curious on why you are trying to do this, Care to shed a little light on the use case ?

Comment: This smells of middle management making technical decisions

Comment: Use case- Someone is paying for my JSON data. During their dev cycle, I don't want them to have to pay for it, so I want to munge it up so it's structurally valid, just not the actual data they'll be getting once they are actually paying me.

Comment: @Hairgami_Master Why not generate dummy data instead? You say you're picking the obfuscated characters/digits randomly anyway, so you could perhaps make prototypes that would return random values of the correct type to build your JSON lists from. Or are you yourself not generating the data?

Comment: He essentially is generating dummy data.

Comment: @numbers1311407 My point was more that, if he's the one distributing the JSON, he should have knowledge of the structure already and shouldn't need to parse existing data to generate data for development. (That assumes he isn't just acting as a middleman, of course.) By using a generator rather than a parser/obfuscator, the structure could be controlled and all possible combinations could be set up to be tested rather than just those from existing data. I feel that that would make more sense for testing purposes even if obfuscation is easier to implement.

Comment: @JAB Thank you for the idea. I should have mentioned I'm not generating the original data, but am in fact a 'middleman' as numbers1311407 suggested.

Comment: 'middleman' as @JAB suggested- you're one step ahead of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function recurse(mem, val, key) {
  if (_.isObject(val)) {
    mem[key] = _.reduce(val, recurse, {});
  } else {
    mem[key] = obfuscate(val);
  }
  return mem;
}

function obfuscate(value) {
  return "bananas!"; // your obfuscate logic
}

var yourObject = {
  foo: "bar",
  baz: { bizz: "buzz", ok: true }
}

var o = _.reduce(yourObject, recurse, {});
console.log(o);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uEwJY/

Answer (score 2):

I've added the `scramble` function to underscore with `mixin`: http://jsfiddle.net/ejWCD/2/

```
var target = {
 "weather": "Cloudy",
 "outsideWeather": {
     "forecast": "Stormy",
     "outside": 48
 },
 "degrees": 12,
 "snowing": false
};

_.mixin({
    scramble: function(obj) {
        var newobj = {};
        _(obj).each(function(el, key) {
            switch( typeof el ) {
                case 'object':
                    newobj[key] = _(el).scramble();
                    break;
                case 'boolean':
                    newobj[key] = !el;
                    break;
                case 'string':
                    newobj[key] = el.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, 'aeiou'.charAt(_.random(4)));
                    break;
                case 'number':
                    newobj[key] = _.random(el*10);
                    break;
            }
        });
        return newobj;
    }
});

console.log( _(target).scramble() );
```

Comment: Many thanks David- this works perfectly. I went with numbers answer, but yours was just as good. Thank you so much for helping me with this! +1 for the random.vowel trick- Never seen that one before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
var obfuscate = function(object) {
    if(_.isNumber(object)) {
        return object + 1;
    } else if(_.isString(object)) {
        return object.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
    } else if(_.isBoolean(object)) {
        return Math.random() >= 5;
    } else if(_.isArray(object)) {
        return _.map(object, obfuscate);
    } else if(_.isObject(object)) {
        return _.object(_.map(object, function(value, key) {
            return [key, obfuscate(value)];
        }));
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not obfuscating the `key`. You can easily change a line of code if you want to do that. Also, if the object is an Array, I'm obfuscating every element.

Test:

```
var input = {
 "weather": "Cloudy",
 "outsideWeather": {
     "forecast": "Stormy",
     "outside": 48
 },
 "degrees": 12,
 "snowing": false
};

console.log(obfuscate(input));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/K2EML/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this Dogbert. This worked perfectly- I went with another answer, but seriously- thank you so much for your code ideas. Cheers!